# $http is not working, but request is working in mean stack web app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a controller(login.controller.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var config = require('config.json');

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
// log vendor out
delete req.session.token;

// move success message into local variable so it only appears once (single read)
var viewData = { success: req.session.success };
delete req.session.success;

res.render('login', viewData);
});

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
// authenticate using api to maintain clean separation between layers
request.post({
    url: config.apiUrl + '/vendors/authenticate',
    form: req.body,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        return res.render('login', { error: 'An error occurred' });
    }

    if (!body.token) {
        return res.render('login', { error: body, vendorname: req.body.vendorname });
    }

    // save JWT token in the session to make it available to the angular app
    req.session.token = body.token;

    // redirect to returnUrl
    var returnUrl = req.query.returnUrl && decodeURIComponent(req.query.returnUrl) || '/';
    res.redirect(returnUrl);
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Where var request is working accessing Remote REST Api. Where as I have one service(vendor.service.js) which has $http not request. But $http is not working:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
.module('app')
.factory('VendorService', Service);




function Service($http, $q) {
var service = {};
//Store
service.GetCurrent = GetCurrent;//st_details
return service;

function GetCurrent() {
    return $http('http://localhost:3000/api/vendors/st_details').then(handleSuccess, handleError);
}
function handleSuccess(res) {
    alert('hi3');
    alert(res.data);
    return res.data;
}

function handleError(res) {
    alert('hi2');
    alert(JSON.stringify(res));
    return $q.reject(res.data);
}
}

})();
```

Can I use "var request = require('request');" in this vendor.service.js if yes how? Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: are you getting an error? If yes, what does it say?

Comment: The response with $http is: `{
  "data": null,
  "status": -1,
  "config":
  {
    "method": "GET",
    "transformRequest": [null],
    "transformResponse": [null],
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/api/vendors/st_details",
    "headers":
    {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1OWRlMjY5Y2UyMzY3NGMyMWQzNDNkNWYiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTY5MzU5NTUsImV4cCI6MTUxNjk3OTE1NX0.F9p9n9lMIgABKjv7CsAgzlxg7NtOzU6R1CDOsD6lBbI"
    }
  },
  "statusText": ""
}`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not using CORS, which you need to use in order to allow apps to access your API via $http.get

Follow the instructions on https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors to add CORS to your express application and it should work.